# Pandas quantiles misbehaving by... getting smaller partway through a range of percentiles?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

**Short version**

Running `df2.groupby("EquipmentType").quantile([.1, .25, .5, .75,0.9,0.95,0.99])` on a dataset is *sometimes* giving me percentiles that appear to reset partway through my data.  Why is this, and how can I avoid it?

Full version of code (but not the data) at the end.

```
Loaders                       0.10    57.731806
                              0.25   394.004375
                              0.50     0.288889
                              0.75     7.201528
                              0.90    51.015667
                              0.95    83.949833
                              0.99   123.148019
```

**Full version**

I'm working through a large dataset (on the order of 2,500,000 rows) of equipment failure data. So imagine a condensed array, with 2 columns x 2,500,000 rows (this is a subset of a 40-something column dataset) that contains one row for every time a bit of equipment failed.

```
EquipmentType         TTF
Pump                   10
Conveyor               20
Crusher                15
...
       <2,500,000 more entries>
...
Pump                    5
Conveyor               20
Pump                   40
Loader                 33
```

TTF in this table stands for Time To Failure.

For context, I have placed this unsorted dataset into dataframe `df2`

I have generated typical descriptive statistics for each bit of equipment, like count, min, mean, max, etc, so I could see what was going on in my data.

```
                               Count       Min        Mean          Max
EquipmentType
Pump                           204136  0.000556   71.797146  23407.41667
CoffeeMachine                  152248  0.001111   66.352893  22939.39306
```

It has a lot of... not quite outliers, but let's say it has some very big entries (maybe 5% of the failure data are very big numbers), and so I am looking for a bit more detail on what is going on.  Enter **quantiles**.

I query the 10, 25, 50, 75, 90, 95 and 99 percentile values in my dataset, and print the result.

`print(df2.groupby("EquipmentType").quantile([.1, .25, .5, .75,0.9,0.95,0.99]) )`

These work well for some equipment types, but not for others.  They should be ever-increasing, but for some equipment items, they suddenly "reset", and start from zero again.

Most look like this, with an array including the equipment type, the percentile being referred to, and the time to fail that matches that percentile...

```
Pumps                         0.10     0.005556
                              0.25     0.238889
                              0.50     1.775000
                              0.75     2.595833
                              0.90     4.611389
                              0.95     7.008125
                              0.99    15.465278
```

But then one or two EquipmentTypes have an abrupt change where they start to consider smaller values than the previous quantile:

```
Loaders                       0.10    57.731806
                              0.25   394.004375
                              0.50     0.288889   <-- What just happened here?
                              0.75     7.201528
                              0.90    51.015667
                              0.95    83.949833
                              0.99   123.148019

Conveyors                     0.10   359.597167
                              0.25   850.714306
                              0.50  7328.187222
                              0.75     0.200000   <-- What just happened here?
                              0.90     0.375000
                              0.95     0.441667
                              0.99     0.500000
```

I have no idea why this could be happening, and I'd like it to stop.

I've checked that quantile doesn't need the data to be in any particular order.

I note that when the dataset is imported, it says that it has multiple data types.  Everything so far seems to deal with that "potential" garbage (not sure what else could possibly be in there... shouldn't be anything non-numeric, at least).

I would like to only look at the entries that are double precision values , but maybe there are some stray things in there (I'm not sure how to pull out examples of those without trying to dump this into EXCEL, which would be a new challenge).

I'd appreciate anyone's thoughts on this.

**Full version of code**

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
data_folder = Path("C:/Users/myName/Documents")
file_to_open = data_folder / "myData.csv"

dashboard_df=pd.read_csv(file_to_open, sep=',',encoding= 'unicode_escape',low_memory =False )

df2=dashboard_df[["CC_CauseLocationEquipmentType", "CC_TBF"]]

df3=df2[df2.CC_TBF.notnull()]

summaryStats=df3.groupby("CC_CauseLocationEquipmentType").count()
summaryStats["Min"]=df3.groupby("CC_CauseLocationEquipmentType").min()
summaryStats["Mean"]=df3.groupby("CC_CauseLocationEquipmentType").mean()
summaryStats["Max"]=df3.groupby("CC_CauseLocationEquipmentType").max()
summaryStats.rename(columns={"CC_TBF": "Count"}, errors="raise")

print("Unfiltered dataset")
print(summaryStats)

print("Quantiles")
print(df3.groupby("CC_CauseLocationEquipmentType").quantile([.1, .25, .5, .75,0.9,0.95,0.99]) )
```

Comment: can you post the data somewhere?

Comment: Please post all of the code you're using to identify the issue. This would be a significant bug, and while that's totally possible, it's far more likely is somewhere else in your code is introducing this bug. If possible, provide data or code to generate data that demonstrates the issue. See this post on creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thanks!

Comment: The original dataset is not something I can release, and so I generated a massive sanitised dataset... and I had no bug as a result.  So, looks like something in my input data is likely causing the problem.  I'll find out what it is, and put something up here.

Comment: OK, so I've now gone back to the original dataset, and stripped out all rows that had empty values for TTF.  This has not made any difference.  

Interestingly, making a new dataframe by filtering for one of the problem equipment types - Loaders, for example, and running quantile on that new Loaders-only data frame avoids the broken-quantiles symptom.  ...but... doing this way for each equipment type goes back to a non-python, non-fun way of doing it... namely, making some loops.

Comment: Hi @MichaelDelgado - I've now added the full (MRE) version of the code.

Comment: It's not actually reproducible, in that you still don't have a non-proprietary dataset that can reproduce the behavior, right? Just making sure. I haven't been able to reproduce this, despite giving it an honest go.

Comment: what version of pandas are you using?