# PANDAS Quantiles different answer depending on how we ask it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, quantile

*New take on a problem from two days ago.*

When you have a big set of data, PANDAS can let you filter things in-place while generating statistics, so you don't have to make new dataframes for everything.  Right now, I suspect there's a nuance to doing this, as doing things two different ways - one the 'smart' way, and one the 'explicit' way, gives me very difference answers, and one is clearly right (the explicit), and one is clearly wrong (the smart way).

Can someone point me in the direction of what I'm missing.

Here's are details.

I've got 2.5 million rows of data, describing the time to failure for a range of different equipment types.  Descriptive statistics for two of these are below.  (Note these are actually mining equipment, but I have to sanitise something, so I've replaced the names).

```
                                   Count        Min        Mean          Max
CC_CauseLocationEquipmentType                                           
Coffee Machines                    204136  0.000556   71.797146  23407.41667
Blenders                            52424  0.008333  750.880591  23077.79167
```

If I try to get quantiles of the failure times for the equipment, using

`print(df2.groupby("CC_CauseLocationEquipmentType").quantile([.1, .25, .5, .75,0.9,0.95,0.99,0.99999]))`

then I see the following quantiles.

```
                                            CC_TBF
CC_CauseLocationEquipmentType                     
Coffee Machines               0.10000     0.005556
                              0.25000     0.238889
                              0.50000     1.775000
                              0.75000     2.595833
                              0.90000     4.611389
                              0.95000     7.008125
                              0.99000    15.465278
                              0.99999    21.089619    <-- Nowhere near the max of 23407.41667
Blenders                      0.10000    57.731806
                              0.25000   394.004375
                              0.50000     0.288889
                              0.75000     7.201528
                              0.90000    51.015667
                              0.95000    83.949833
                              0.99000   123.148019
                              0.99999   133.708716    <-- Nowhere near the max of 23077.79167
```

This is clearly incorrect because the 99.999% quantile is nowhere near the maximum values for those equipment types.  **Also note the 'reset' partway through the Blender quantile dataset.  I asked about this previously with 
[Pandas quantiles misbehaving by... getting smaller partway through a range of percentiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62254156/pandas-quantiles-misbehaving-by-getting-smaller-partway-through-a-range-of-pe)  That's still unresolved, but I think this new question will help solve that problem as well.**

When I consider the quantiles separately, I get more sensible results.  Using the following code:

```
print("Quantiles - type by type - Coffee Machines")
df3=df2.loc[df2['CC_CauseLocationEquipmentType'] == "Coffee Machines"]
print(df3.quantile([.1, .25, .5, .75,0.9,0.95,0.99,0.99999]) )

print("Quantiles - type by type - Blenders")
df3=df2.loc[df2['CC_CauseLocationEquipmentType'] == "Blenders"]
print(df3.quantile([.1, .25, .5, .75,0.9,0.95,0.99,0.99999]) )
```

I now get:

```
Quantiles - type by type - Coffee Machines
               CC_TBF
0.10000      0.120556
0.25000      0.608333
0.50000      2.040556
0.75000      3.494514
0.90000     18.047917
0.95000    129.798403
0.99000   1644.764861
0.99999  23003.517729   <-- Pretty darn close to the max of 23407
Quantiles - type by type - Blenders
               CC_TBF
0.10000      0.226111
0.25000      0.941667
0.50000     37.924167
0.75000    388.554444
0.90000   1955.252500
0.95000   4301.835320
0.99000  11362.310594
0.99999  22831.372845   <--- pretty darn close to the max of 23077
```

Can anyone tell me why these two different approaches give such different results, and why my use of `groupby` is giving me such a weird, seemingly arbitrary result?  Does `groupby` somehow use a different sub-set of the full data than what I have done in the second "explicit" approach?

Comment: Please check https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27526 if you have that version or if the issue is the same. Hm, but there it crashes...

Comment: But for easier debugging, please try the code from the first post and apply your two different versions. This should show the same behaviour but be easier to grip.

Comment: By the way, please rewrite your question above using sample data like that. We need a minimum working example. No need to mention millions of rows, which kind of data or else. Something small and neat is easier to deal with and usually shows the same behaviour. A people can just copy paste the code and try it without you having to post lots of data or people having to ask for it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi @Joe - I tried to grab a smaller set of the same data, and didn't see the problem.  I also tried to generate a dummy data set of the same size, and didn't see the problem.  Note that in both cases, I was using the same Python code, but no longer saw the glitch.  So, it would seem I would either have to release the original data set, *or* spend more time debugging this than my current schedule will allow, especially since I now have a workaround.  I would like to help get to the bottom of this in case it is a problem with the routine, but that will have to wait - and may never happen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting. There is clearly a bug at least in my version of Pandas (0.25.1) with `df.groupby(...).quantile(<array-like>)`. That [codepath is different](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blame/master/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L2085) and seems to be broken even on very simple examples like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"A": [0., 0., 0.], "B": ["X", "Y", "Z"]}
)
result = df.groupby("B").quantile([0.5, 0.9])
```

While it would work on a 2-element version one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"A": [0., 0.], "B": ["X", "Y"]}
)
result = df.groupby("B").quantile([0.5, 0.9])
```

I would avoid using groupby with quantile on array-like objects until the code is fixed even in cases it works now since it is likely error-prone.

Blame also shows a lot of fairly fresh updates there (10, 16 months) dealing exactly with these pieces of code too.

Comment: Just to clarify - on pandas version 0.25.1 the first example was throwing `IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds` exception on quantile call.

Answer (score 1):

You can't see quantile at work in both examples in the answer from @alexander-pivovarov. There are only zeros and only one element for each group, so the result is always zero. Or am I wrong here?

I have pandas 0.25.3 and get useful results for

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"A": [1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.], "B": ["X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z"]}
)
result = df.groupby("B").quantile([0.5, 0.9])
print(result)
```

Output:

```
        A
B         
X 0.5  1.5
  0.9  1.9
Y 0.5  3.5
  0.9  3.9
Z 0.5  5.5
  0.9  5.9
```

If it works with a single number passed to `quantiles()` you could hack something like

```
q = [0.2, 0.5, 0.9]
res = [df.groupby("B").quantile(_).loc['X', 'A'] for _ in q]

df_q = pd.DataFrame({'A':res, 'quantiles':q})

print(df_q)
```

Output:

```
     A  quantiles
0  1.2        0.2
1  1.5        0.5
2  1.9        0.9
```

until it is fixed.

Comment: Just to clarify - running the example with zeros on 0.25.1 is supposed to throw an exception. Version 0.25.3 however is working just fine on that example (no exception).